# Delete rows for multiple csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I am trying to merge multiple csv files while deleting the 2 first rows of each file. I came up with something like this :

```
@echo off
(for %%f in (*.csv) do more +2 "%%f") >> output.csv
echo Done.
```

There are 12 files of 26Mo (253 612 rows in each file).
But the process  stops at row 65 534, making a 6Mo file.

Comment: You can probably speed it up with `(for %%f in (*.csv) do more +2 "%%f")>output.csv` (speed gain depends on how many files there are).  Can't help you with ` does not even give what I want`, because we don't know how the result differs from your expectations.

Comment: Using `more` will change any horizontal tabs to a series of spaces, so I definitely would not advise using it with tab delimited CSVs, technically TSVs.

Comment: @Stephan yes sorry for the bad precision, I have edited it. Thanks !

Comment: @Vianey, did you try using the code Stephan gave you? If so please [edit] your question to include any differences in speed with your currently submitted code and explain to us what the issue is with records without data, _(empty lines as you call them)_. Please understand that `more` is not adding lines which do not exist in the source files, so any you are seeing are likely to be the trailing CRLF or LF from the end of those files, or those which already existed elsewhere within them.

Comment: The Stephan's command deleted the blank lines. However, it runs for an infinit time, blocking at row 65 534, while, each .csv contains 253 612 rows.

Comment: If it does not _have_ to be plain batch files, try investigating `awk`, which makes such jobs trivial.

Comment: Maybe information like number of files, and number of records in each would have been better in the question area, especially as any logical thinker would assume that the processing time would be a product of both of those two factors. The `more` utility will prompt for each additional line beyond line 65536, so that information is crucial to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest way to do that in a Batch file:

```
@echo off

(for %%f in (*.csv) do (
   < "%%f" ( 
      set /P "=" & set /P "="
      findstr "^"
   )
)) > output.tmp

ren output.tmp output.csv
```